How to Install Real-Time Kernel Patch on Ubuntu 6.11.0 Raspi Server for Raspberry Pi 3 B+?
I have Linux Ubuntu 6.11.0 Raspi Server installed on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I need to install a real-time kernel patch on it. Could someone guide me through the process?
